# What to put as a role when using a preloader

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I'm reading over aria right now and I have a preloader (spinner) and it doesnt show how much percentage is loaded. I can use

```
 <div aria-busy="true" aria-label="Loading, please wait." role=""></div>
```

But what role should I use? It's not a progressbar since I dont have a percentage or any indicator how much is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use progressbar even if you don't have a percentage.  That's what we do.

```
<div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" role="progressbar" aria-labelledby="__indicator1-label">
```

We don't use aria-busy but perhaps we should.  We also use window.setTimeout() and update a visually invisible `<span role="alert">` every X number of seconds so that the screen reader can hear "still loading" (or whatever text you want to use).  We don't update any percentage, we just keep refreshing the "still loading" message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following role for the loader.

```
role="progressbar"
```